# How to display the selected item of Select tag in another tag in Blade in Laravel 8?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, node-blade

I want to display the selected item of Select tag in p tag and when i run the code it doesn't work, this is my code :

```
<label for="modelResp"> Response </label>
<select name="modelResp" id="modelResp" onchange="myFunction()">
     @foreach ($destins as $dest)
        <option 
           value="{{$dest->design_destin}}"> {{$dest->design_destin}} 
        </option>
     @endforeach
</select>

<p id="demo"> **I want to display the selected item here** </p>
@push('scripts')
    <script>
          function myFunction() {
             var x = document.getElementById("modelResp").value;
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x;
          }
     </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: Does something not work? Do you get any errors in console, if so, what are the errors?

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: Nothing in the console? Did you try to `console.log(x)` in your `myFunction()`? Is your script loaded? Do you have a stack named `scripts` in your blade somewhere?

Comment: have you checked the generated html code?

Comment: could you get the value x in js...???

Comment: check the example, it's working fine https://jsfiddle.net/nhbq18wf/

Comment: @Jon What did you change?

Comment: I deleted : @push('scripts') , @endpush.                                                                           I deleted var x = document.getElementById("modelResp").value;                                                        and I added (this) to myFunction(this) and I use  select.value;                                         this is exact what you show me in : https://jsfiddle.net/nhbq18wf/